# How to duplicate part of the surface?

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

I am testing media playback with SharpDX and everything is fine, now I would like to split the output view into a grid 2x2 and playback (the same) video in each cell. I imagine I could output data from media engine to part of the surface (`SharpDX.DXGI.Surface`) and then duplicate that part 3 times giving appropriate coordinates of the target rectangle.

I don't see any relevant method on surface, so how to do it?

Comment: Play the video on a, quater size of the screen, texture and use the `CopySubresourceRegion` to duplicate it on all four cells

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, thank you! I use the sample code of SharpDX though which uses just surface to playback movies, not texture.

Comment: If I google [sharpdx video playback example](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/StoreApp/OldSamplesToBeBackPorted/CommonDX/MediaPlayer.cs) I got this on the first hit. Line 68 says `public SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D OutputVideoTexture;`. I haven't tested it. Just did a google. So you might try my previous suggestion.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, ha, thank you once again, you hit StoreApp branch, while I was using the codes from the Desktop (since I write for desktop), but  it gave me enough of ideas. Thank you very much!